# Filter words only instead of punctuations

Tags: python, list, find-occurrences

I'm attempting to go through lists of positive (`'pos'`) and negative (`'neg'`) lists essentially. Issue here is that the script below is including out white-space and punctuation also, and I don't want that. I would like to only extract the most common 30 words from these lists. Any idea on how this can be done?

```
#for counting frequently occurrence of negative and positive words.

from collections import Counter

count1 = Counter(" ".join(data[data['sentiment']=='pos']["text"]).split()).most_common(30)
data1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(count1)
data1 = data1.rename(columns={0: "words of positive", 1 : "count"})
count2 = Counter(" ".join(data[data['sentiment']=='neg']["text"]).split()).most_common(30)
data2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(count2)
data2 = data2.rename(columns={0: "words of negative", 1 : "count_"})
```

**EDIT**

Above implementation has the right idea, however I am looking to extract words with meaning and not logical connectives such as (the, and a it that) as well as punctuations

Comment: Easiest way is to probably preprocess your text with something like `re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', my_string)`, which will remove all punctuation

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `.split()`

```
data[data['sentiment']=='pos']["text"]).split()
```

with a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) function

```
import re

def return_words(string):
    return re.findall(r'\b\S+\b', string.lower())

return_words(data[data['sentiment']=='pos']["text"]))
```

So putting that in your code:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def return_words(string):
    return re.findall(r'\b\S+\b', string.lower())

count1 = Counter(" ".join(return_words(data[data['sentiment']=='pos']["text"]))).most_common(30)
data1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(count1)
data1 = data1.rename(columns={0: "words of positive", 1 : "count"})
count2 = Counter(" ".join(retrn_words(data[data['sentiment']=='neg']["text"]))).most_common(30)
data2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(count2)
data2 = data2.rename(columns={0: "words of negative", 1 : "count_"})
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @Polacan Perhaps try `string.str.lower()`.

Comment: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @Polacan What about `str(string.str)`?

Comment: output shows the first letter I think of the most frequent word (ie. t s  a n ..)

Comment: and numbers as well, when I just want words. *edit but those numbers may be relevant so they can stay that's fine

Comment: What does `data[data['sentiment']=='pos']["text"]).split()` return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228683/discussion-between-polacan-and-ann-zen).